# .lua files don't save corretly

Tags: windows, notepad

So I had a .lua file I wanted to modify, I selected open with notepad, and I was finished editing it, so I saved it as a .lua file but it just saves it as a notepad file. I have searched online and no "solutions" are helping. Please help?

I am using Windows 10

Answer (score 1):

Be sure you click on `All Files` on the dropdown menu when saving, instead of letting the default extension, `.txt`, be added. Otherwise your file ends up being saved as `whatever.lua.txt`.